# How can I apply Java functions to Scala Option in Java code

Tags: java, scala, primitive-types, language-interoperability, scala-option

Given Scala Options `Option[String]`, `Option[Long]`, `Option[Boolean]` and given Java consumers for `String`, `long`, `boolean` I want to apply these cleanly, with static type checks, in Java code.
The problem is, `Option[Long]` and `Option[Boolean]` become `Option<Object>` in Java code, so I need an unchecked type cast:

```
<T> void acceptIfDefinedPrimitive(Option<Object> option, Consumer<T> consumer) {
    if (option.isDefined()) {
        consumer.accept((T) option.get());
    }
}
```

The other solution I've found is specialized Scala function for each primitive type:

```
def acceptIfDefined[T](option: Option[T], consumer: Consumer[T]):Unit = {
  if (option.isDefined) {
    consumer.accept(option.get)
  }
}

def acceptIfDefinedLong(option: Option[Long], consumer: Consumer[java.lang.Long]):Unit = {
  if (option.isDefined) {
    consumer.accept(option.get)
  }
}

def acceptIfDefinedBoolean(option: Option[Boolean], consumer: Consumer[java.lang.Boolean]):Unit = {
  if (option.isDefined) {
    consumer.accept(option.get)
  }
}
```

But actually, on the Java side the latter two look like `acceptIfDefinedLong(Option<Object>, Consumer<java.lang.Long>)` so there is actually no strict type check.

- How can I do this?
- How can I generalize this?
- How can I write this in Java?
- Is it possible at all?

Must be callable from Java and must not have unchecked casts.